# Submit video via contact form more then 25 mb limit

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I have wordpress site where users need to submit their videos. I use contact form 7 as for contact form. It works ok, but with one problem - i couldn't submit file bigger than 25 mb as it is limit which could be send as email. So i looking for solution which would allow users submit videos bigger than 25 mb. I think solution should be like during form submitting file should be uploaded to some storage like gdrive or dropbox and on email admin should get link to file instead file.

Answer (score 1):

A limit of 25 MB is set in the ContactForm 7 plugin database.
You need to open the file *config-validator.php* in path contact-form-7/includes
, find the line 528:

```
$max = 25 * 1024 * 1024; // 25 MB
```

Here, change the number 25 to the desired size of the downloaded files. Remember to change the restriction in the form template.